# django convert .values_list('datetimefield') to date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

I would like to convert a a values_list field with a datetime object to a date object.

`.values_list('time_finished', flat=True)`

gives me "2016-03-22T18:52:53.486Z"  and what I would like is
"2016-03-22"

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to get `datetime.date` object:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 12, 15, 54, 48, 401418)
>>> dt.date()
datetime.date(2016, 4, 12)
```

Use [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to get string:

```
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2016-04-12'
```

---

```
[dt.date() for dt in query.values_list('time_finished', flat=True)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to run some database functions directly such as using `DATE`:

```
queryset = queryset.extra(select={'time_finished_date': 'DATE(time_finished)'}).values_list('time_finished_date', flat=True)
```

If you print the SQL query from the `queryset`, it will look something like this:

```
>>> print(queryset.query)
# SELECT (DATE(time_finished)) AS "time_finished_date" FROM <<tablename>>
```