# Django filter based on start date and end date for single day

Tags: mysql, django

I have a query

```
start_date = '2019-11-17'
end_date = '2019-11-18'

events = Event.objects.filter(start_date__gte=start_date,end_date__lte=end_date)
```

This doesn't return any result.. I tried direct mysql query, even this doesn't return any results,

```
SELECT * FROM `events` where start_date >= '2019-11-17' and end_date <= '2019-11-18'
```

Any idea where I am wrong?

In my database I have these 3 rows,

[image]

This works,

```
SELECT * FROM `events` where start_date > '2019-11-17' and end_date < '2019-11-19'
```

But why not **<= '2019-11-18'**?? any idea?

I managed to add 1 day to the end_date to resolve it.

**MY SOLUTION**

```
start_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(start_date/1000.0)
end_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(end_date/1000.0)

start_date = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = (end_date + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

NOW THIS WORKS

```
events = Event.objects.filter(start_date__gt=start_date,end_date__lt=end_date)
```

Comment: What type are the `start_date` and `end_date` columns?  Are they date or datetime?  In any case, most likely you just don't have matching data for these dates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen datetime.. But adjusting the start date to ``SELECT * FROM `events` where start_date >= '2019-10-30' and end_date <= '2019-11-18'`` returns result the first row in the screenshot.. I guess I am wrong somewhere with end_date

Comment: Are you trying to find any record whose _range_ intersects with the dates contained in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually my query should return the 2nd and 3rd row from the screenshot, that is my goal for this range ``start_date >= '2019-11-17' and end_date <= '2019-11-18'``

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your effort to find out the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your date is beyond `2019-11-18`, cast your `datetime` columns as `date`

```
SELECT * FROM `events` where cast(start_date as date) >= '2019-11-17' and cast(end_date as date) <= '2019-11-18'
```

if you are going to evaluate below expression, it will `return 0`

```
select cast('2019-11-18 16:23:01' as datetime)  <= '2018-11-18'
```

Comment: I got result from the casting as you wrote, but I am thinking of how to implement it with django queryset objects

Comment: @overflow, you might try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565611/django-convert-values-listdatetimefield-to-date

Comment: You answer gave me some idea, accepting it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use django Queryset to filter a datetime field just by the date:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(start_date__date__gte=start_date, end_date__date__lte=end_date)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#date

Comment: Hope this should work.. Will try and let you know it